# DisplayFor silently fails for cast model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My application has 2 types of contacts, Employees and Customers.

So we have:

> IContact
>
> Contact : IContact
>
> Customer : Contact
>
> Employee : Contact

I have created a view where I attempt to display the correct template depending on the type of the model. This silently fails and nothing is displayed.

```
    @model IContact
    @{
        var customer = Model as Customer;
        var employee = Model as Employee;
    }

    @if (customer != null) 
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => customer, "CustomerInfo")         
    }
    else if (employee != null)
    {    
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => employee, "EmployeeInfo")      
    }
```

I'm sure this should be easy, but I don't know the correct way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "it silently fails"? Do you get the correct object after the casting? Do your views (`CustomerInfo`, `EmployeeInfo`) ever get reached?

Comment: It reaches DisplayFor but the views never get reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DisplayFor` helper is searching for a property that matches `customer` or `employee` but it will never find it. You should instead render the view as a partial. This allows you to select the view you want to render and also pass a strongly typed model:

```
@if (customer != null) 
{
    @Html.Partial(CustomerInfo", customer)         
}
else if (employee != null)
{    
    @Html.Partial("EmployeeInfo", employee)      
}
```

Comment: You don't even need to do this. DisplayFor is smart enough to know what real type you have and display the appropriate template for you (as long as you have a view in DisplayTemplates that matches the class name. That is, if you do @Html.DisplayForModel() it will use Customer.cshtml or Employee.cshtml depending on which type of object  it is.